# iOS Setting text background color in UILabel (with rounded rectangle shape)

Tags: ios, css, objective-c

I need to create something like this.

[image]

One of the way is to create like this. I can append image (for "PDF").

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init]; attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyIcon.png"];

NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My label text"]; [myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

myLabel.attributedText = myString;
```

But I not sure whether it is good. Is there any alternative way? Can I highlight 'PDF' word with rounded background? I can easily set text background color with attributed string but it won't have rounded corner.

Comment: Why don't you try to use cornerRadius property of label's layer ??Like this label.layer.cornerRadius = 7;

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I only have 1 label and need to change background color for only 'PDF'.

Comment: PDF is your label right?

Comment: PDF and 01.16 - ASN Incident Noti....   the whole string will be in 1 label. If it is 2 label, I can't align 'PDF' and Reminder like that.

Answer (score 4):

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
myLabel.layer.cornerRedius = 5.0;
myLabel.laayer.maskToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would embed the UILabel for PDF in another UIView with the desired background color, and round the corners using view.layer.cornerRadius. This way you can adjust the UILabel how you want within the rounded view.

If you round the corners on the UILabel, you risk having your text overlap the rounded edges.

Answer (score 1):

Use RTLabel library to convert the HTML text. I have used it several times. It works. Here is link to the library and a sample code.

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel.

and then apply the css style you need

Hope I helped.